# How to add a shared layout when using NextJS and Auth0?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, server-side-rendering, auth0

I've followed the Next docs to set up my layouts, which is working fine.  However, the NextJS Auth0 SDK has a `withPageAuthRequired` wrapped that breaks this pattern.

The pattern I'm using is from these [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts).  For example, here is a page component:

```
function Page(): ReactElement {
  return <DashboardLayout>"Code Detail Page"</DashboardLayout>
}

Page.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return <DashboardLayout>{page}</DashboardLayout>
}

export default withPageAuthRequired(Page)
```

And then in my `_app.tsx`:

```
type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode
}

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page)

  return (
    <UserProvider>
        {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
    </UserProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

The problem I have with this is that my layout is no longer pulled, which I'm assuming is because of the Auth0 wrapper.

If I do the following, I'm able to render the layout, but I need to add a `// @ts-ignore` before the `AuthWrapper.getLayout` assignment.

```
const AuthWrapper = withPageAuthRequired(Page)

AuthWrapper.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return <DashboardLayout>{page}</DashboardLayout>
}
export default AuthWrapper
```

Is there an alternative way to use layouts with this pattern that doesn't require adding `// @ts-ignore` to all of my authenticated pages?

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the return type of `withPageAuthRequired()` is a function that's expected to be called serverside, and the return type of that function is a Promise.  Next time I'm working on this project I'll try some things along these lines to see if I can get it working without any TS hacks

Comment: You can extend the type of `withPageAuthRequired` to also include `getLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using `withPageAuthRequired` wrong. It is used to wrap the `getServerSideProps`, not the page.

> If you wrap your getServerSideProps with WithPageAuthRequired your
> props object will be augmented with the user property, which will be
> the user's Claims

```
export const getServerSideProps = withPageAuthRequired({
  getServerSideProps: async ({ req, res }) => {
    const auth0User = getSession(req, res);
    ... add logic here

    return {
      props: {
        myProp,
      },
    };
  },
});
```

Comment: Just wanted to share an update saying that this was indeed the issue.  Once I fixed that, everything to do with Typescript was happy

Comment: It's not the official documentation : [official auth0 youtube channel](https://youtu.be/egnVe9lXY0E?t=404)